# Multi-lingual approach for Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, multilingual, translate

I would like to implement an app with multiple languages support.
I would like to use core data but I don't know how to feature the different languages.

Do I have to create two separate databases? What is the best approach?!

Thanks you all guys, yassa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found a working solution, but I don't know if this is the best approach.

I've only one database, but in its schema, for each main entity, I've create another entity to store translations in many different languages:

## entity (1:M) entity_translation

In my translation tables, I've a "language" column to store information about the locale to with the row is referring to.

Hope it helps,
yassa

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to localize?  It depends on your data, though I'd see very little reason to have multiple databases.

If you want to localize the strings in your Core Data, and they're finite, you can store localization keys and translation via Localizable.strings.

Generally your data isn't localized, your strings are.  i.e., if someone provides their name, it's not translated.

Comment: my data are, for example, poem name and poem. And I want these contents to be available in English and French. What is the best approach? Use core data? Use plist?